# Matrix of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I have troubles with following problem, can you please help me?

Matrix of linear operator $f$ over the field $\mathbf{Z}_5^3$
to a canonical base is $A$.
$$A=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1 & 4\\
3 & 0 & 2 \\
4 & 4 & 3
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

Find base $B$ over the field $\mathbf{Z}_5^3$
so the matrix $f$ to $B$ was $[f]_B^B = $
$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c & 1 & 0 \\
0 & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c
\end{array} 
\right)
$
for some $c \in \mathbf{Z}_5$.

Thanks.

Comment: You're being asked to diagonalize $A$. Where is your problem occurring? Is it working over $\Bbb Z_5$? or diagonalization in general? or worry about whether the final diagonalized form will match what $B$ has to be? What have you tried?

Comment: There is a reason why one writes \begin{array}{ccc} with "{ccc}".  It has to do with the reason why one uses alignment tabs.  But you didn't use any alignment tabs, the "{ccc}" didn't serve its purpose.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** We calculate the characteristic polynomial over $\Bbb Z_5$ to be
$$
\det\pmatrix{3-t&1&4\\3&-t&2\\4&4&3-t} = \\
(3-t)[t(t-3) - (2)(4)] - 1[3(3-t) - (2)(4)] + 4[3(4) + 4t]
$$
Your $c$ must be the unique zero of this polynomial.  Modulo $5$, we have
$$
(3-t)[t(t-3) - (2)(4)] - 1[3(3-t) - (2)(4)] + 4[3(4) + 4t] = \\
(3-t)[t^2 - 3t + 2] - [1 - 3t] - [2 - t] = \\
-t^3 + t^2 - t + 1 - [1 - 3t] - [2 - t] =\\
-t^3 + t^2 - 2t - 2
$$
Now, there are $5$ possibilities.  Check them.